# Cronjobs are not running by www-data

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron, alpine-linux

I'm working on a Laravel app deployed on a Kubernetes cluster, and I need to set a cronjob to run `php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run`.

I'm using `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` image.

The following script is used to generate the cronjob:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

crontab -l > mycron

touch /var/cronlogs.txt

echo "* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /var/cronlogs.txt 2>&1" >> mycron

crontab mycron

rm mycron
```

The cronjob is working fine, but suddenly I faced an issue that when some of the php artisan commands executed by the cronjob, it writes the log in `storage/logs` with root permissions which denied `www-data` requests from writing logs.

I tried to change the user who runs the cronjob to `www-data`, but when I did that the cronjob is not running anymore.

##### What I Did:

1. I changed `crontab -l > mycron` to `crontab -u www-data -l > mycron` and `crontab mycron` to `crontab -u www-data mycron` in the script.
2. I changed the ownership of `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data` to `www-data:www-data`.
3. I ran `crond` command.

There were no errors when I ran `crond` command but the job did not start.

The cronjob in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` works fine (with the changing log file issue).

The cronjob in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data` doesn't work.

How to make cronjobs run by `www-data`? and if this is not the solution how to prevent php artisan commands from writing logs by root user?

Comment: Double-check your logs in `/var/logs`, either in a dedicated cron log or maybe syslog. See if there's any error messages there.

Comment: What does `crontab -l` yield?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your PHP is running under the root user. You can check the PHP process by running the command `ps aux | grep php`.
Additionally, you can check the user for the Apache process by running the command `ps aux | grep apache`

Comment: You forgot to share how to resolve the problem. Also, why should it be relevant which user the Apache process uses?